# Linear constraints in Quadratic equation

Tags: optimization, quadratics

I have been going through [this](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~yweiss/Colorization/) paper, and wish to implement the same algorithm in java. I have also managed to write equivalent code for the same, but I have not completely understood the mathematics of the algorithm. In the section 2 'Algorithm', can anybody explain to me how equation 1, 2, 3 and 4 yield a large sparse system of linear equations?

The algorithm is given as input an intensity volume Y (x, y , t ) and outputs two color volumes U (x, y , t ) and V (x, y , t ). T o simplify notation we will use boldface letters (e.g. r, s) to denote (x, y , t ) triplets. Thus, Y (r) is the intensity of a particular pixel. As mentioned in the introduction, we wish to impose the constraint that two neighboring pixels r, s should have similar colors if their intensities are similar . Thus, we wish to minimize the difference between the color U (r) at pixel r and the weighted average of the colors at neighboring pixels:

eq.1) $J(U) = \sum_{r}{\Big(U(r) - \sum_{s \in N(r)}{w_{rs}U(s)} \Big)^{2}}$

where wrs is a weighting function that sums to one, large when Y (r) is similar to Y (s), and small when the two intensities are different. Similar weighting functions are used extensively in image segmentation algorithms.

eq.2) $w_{rs} \propto e^{-(Y(r) - Y(s))^{2}/2 \sigma_{r}^{2}}$

A second weighting function is based on the normalized correlation between the two intensities:where µr and σr are the mean and variance of the intensities in a
window around r.

eq.3) $w_{rs} \propto 1 + \frac{1}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} \big(Y(r) - \mu_{r} \big) \big(Y(s) - \mu_{r} \big)$

The notation r ∈ N(s) denotes the fact that r and s are neighboring pixels. In a single frame, we define two pixels as neighbors if their image locations are nearby . Between two successive frames, we define two pixels as neighbors if their image locations, after accounting for motion, are nearby . More formally , let vx (x, y), vy (x, y) denote the optical flow calculated at time t . Then the pixel (x0, y0, t ) is a neighbor of pixel (x1, y1, t + 1).

eq.4) $|| (x_{0} + v_{x}(x_{0}), y_{0} + v_{y}(y_{0})) - (x_{1}, y_{1}) || < T$

Now given a set of locations ri where the colors are specified by the user u(ri ) = ui, v(ri ) = vi we minimize J( U ), J( V ) subject to these constraints. Since the cost functions are quadratic and the constraints are linear , this optimization problem yields a large, sparse system of linear equations, which may be solved using a number of standard methods.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.StackExchange. Since you're new, I'd like to recommend the following: providing links to other sources is always welcomed, but you should present the actual material on your post as well. Perhaps here you could copy the algorithm's pseudocode, for example? Or even the equations? Good luck!

Comment: @daOnlyBG : I have edited my question..